# How to use awk to split a file using a text-pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, split

I have a 2Gb file. That has a a header and many-many "event"-structures. This is how the beginning will look:

```
<run example>
<header>
 5
   This is header                                                   
</header>

<event  =             22>
<evhead>
 8
       3       1       2       0       0       0       0       0
       0       0       1       0       1      30       0       1
       4       1       4       3       1       0       1       0
       0       0       0       0       0       1       1       8
       0       1       0       2       1       5       2       0
       2       1       3       7       3       1       1       0
       1       0   10100       2       3       1       5       1
       1       5       1       7       2       3       2       2
</evhead>
 0 97
           3      11       0       0       3       4  1.94791176123E-14  0.00000000000E+00 -2.75000000000E+01  2.75000000047E+01  5.10000000000E-04
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3    2212       0       0       5       0 -1.94791176123E-14  0.00000000000E+00  9.20000000000E+02  9.20000478451E+02  9.38270000000E-01
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3      11       1       0       0       0  4.63012694434E+00  2.62561831936E+00 -2.31855757639E+01  2.37887130977E+01  5.10000000000E-04
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3      22       1       0       0       0 -4.63012694434E+00 -2.62561831936E+00 -4.31442423592E+00  3.71128690719E+00 -5.75956188088E+00
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3    2212       2       0       0       0 -2.16995636615E-14 -1.11022302463E-15  9.20000000000E+02  9.20000478451E+02  9.38270000000E-01
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3      22       4       0       0       0 -4.60626572550E+00 -2.61208727495E+00 -2.23619853289E+00  5.74815342040E+00  0.00000000000E+00
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
</event>
```

The whole file contains 97000 of such "event" blocks. So I want to split this file in 10 files in the way that each would contain the header AND 10 000 of the "event" blocks. All blocks differ by index (they are random). The last file will of course contain only 7 000 blocks.

I have tried multiple instructions from stack like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544197/splitting-a-file-in-linux-based-on-content
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544197/splitting-a-file-in-linux-based-on-content
but non did worked for me.

Below is a bit bigger example of the file for any tests ([file_to_download](https://transfer.sh/TWyEW/test-example.txt)):

```
<run example>
<header>
 5
   header                                                     
</header>

<event  =             22>
<evhead>
 8
       3       1       2       0       0       0       0       0
       0       0       1       0       1      30       0       1
       4       1       4       3       1       0       1       0
</evhead>
 0 97
           3      11       0       0       3       4  1.94791176123E-14  0.00000000000E+00 -2.75000000000E+01  2.75000000047E+01  5.10000000000E-04
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3    2212       0       0       5       0 -1.94791176123E-14  0.00000000000E+00  9.20000000000E+02  9.20000478451E+02  9.38270000000E-01
</event>

<event  =             26>
<evhead>
 8
       3       1       2       0       0       0       0       0
       0       0       1       0       1      30       0       1
       4       1       4       3       1       0       1       0
</evhead>
 0 52
           3      11       0       0       3       4  1.94791176123E-14  0.00000000000E+00 -2.75000000000E+01  2.75000000047E+01  5.10000000000E-04
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3    2212       0       0       5       0 -1.94791176123E-14  0.00000000000E+00  9.20000000000E+02  9.20000478451E+02  9.38270000000E-01
</event>

<event  =             31>
<evhead>
 8
       3       1       2       0       0       0       0       0
       0       0       1       0       1      30       0       1
       4       1       4       3       1       0       1       0
       0       0       0       0       0       1       1       8
</evhead>
 0 92
           3      11       0       0       3       4  1.94791176123E-14  0.00000000000E+00 -2.75000000000E+01  2.75000000047E+01  5.10000000000E-04
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3    2212       0       0       5       0 -1.94791176123E-14  0.00000000000E+00  9.20000000000E+02  9.20000478451E+02  9.38270000000E-01
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3      11       1       0       0       0  4.39003604933E+00  4.97037860337E+00 -2.04926313413E+01  2.15389187176E+01  5.10000000000E-04
</event>

<event  =             37>
<evhead>
 8
       3       1       2       0       0       0       0       0
       0       0       1       0       1      30       0       1
</evhead>
 0 77
           3      11       0       0       3       4  1.94791176123E-14  0.00000000000E+00 -2.75000000000E+01  2.75000000047E+01  5.10000000000E-04
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3    2212       0       0       5       0 -1.94791176123E-14  0.00000000000E+00  9.20000000000E+02  9.20000478451E+02  9.38270000000E-01
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3      11       1       0       0       0  7.91768942174E+00  3.75815788575E+00 -2.09569980000E+01  2.27158385693E+01  5.10000000000E-04
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
</event>

<event  =             41>
<evhead>
 8
       3       1       2       0       0       0       0       0
       0       0       1       0       1      30       0       1
       4       1       4       3       1       0       1       0
</evhead>
 0 122
           3      11       0       0       3       4  1.94791176123E-14  0.00000000000E+00 -2.75000000000E+01  2.75000000047E+01  5.10000000000E-04
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3    2212       0       0       5       0 -1.94791176123E-14  0.00000000000E+00  9.20000000000E+02  9.20000478451E+02  9.38270000000E-01
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
           3      11       1       0       0       0 -3.63469912393E+00  3.95372353695E+00 -1.62133507727E+01  1.70796870892E+01  5.10000000000E-04
                                                      0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00
</event>
```

Comment: Is it an XML file? The snippet looks like one. Have you considering using an XML parser to split out this content? If not, is there any reason why the answer has to include `awk`?

Comment: @roaima actually any native linux utility will do. I am using a computer where I am not allowed to instal any software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `awk`:

```
BEGIN { fname = "/dev/null" }
/<header>/,/<\/header>/ { hdr = hdr $0 "\n"; next }
/^<event / {
    events++
    if(events % 10000 == 1) {
        if(files++) close(fname)
        fname = sprintf("file%02d.txt", files)
        print hdr >fname
    }        
}            
{ print >>fname }
```

To run it: write it to a file `script.awk`, then run:

```
gawk -f script.awk file.txt
```

Comment: I am not sure how to run it. I assume this should be in a script? I have add a bigger file to my questions -  this should be enough to make a test.

Comment: Yes, you need to write it to a file.  Answer updated.

Comment: thanks for clarification. However if I run it - I get no error message and no new files. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, it should actually work now.